# Sorting and Binary search using Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search, recursion

I was asked to sort and search an array. The sorting the array was simple and my code worked but then whenever I try to call the binary search method it works for the first element in the array but gives me "-1" as a result

My full code is as follows:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = new int[5];
    array[0] = 50;
    array[1] = 40;
    array[2] = 10;
    array[3] = 20;
    array[4] = 100;

sort(array, (array.length - 1));

      for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        System.out.println(" " + array[x]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Binary search (R): " + rBsearch(array, 0, (array.length), 20));
}
    public static void sort(int[] a, int last) {
    if (last > 0) {
        int max = findMax(a, last);
        swap(a, last, max);
        sort(a, last - 1);
    }
}

public static int rBsearch(int[] L, int low, int high, int k) {


    int mid = (low + high) / 2;

    if (low > high) {
        return -1;
    } else if (L[mid] == k) {
        return mid;
    } else if (L[mid] < k) {
        return rBsearch(L, k, mid + 1, high);
    } else {
        return rBsearch(L, k, low, mid - 1);
    }
 }

public static int findMax(int[] arr, int last) {

    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= last; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[max]) {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
    }

public static void swap(int[] arr, int last, int max) {
    int temp = arr[last];
    arr[last] = arr[max];
    arr[max] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at your `rBsearch` method - look like you mix up bounds and key in the recursion calls. Maybe add a `println` to see whats actually happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You goofed up the binary search intervals

```
public static int rBsearch(int[] L, int low, int high, int k) {


    int mid = (low + high) / 2;

    if (low > high) {
        return -1;
    } else if (L[mid] == k) {
        return L[mid];
    } else if (L[mid] < k) {
        return rBsearch(L, mid + 1, high, k);
    } else {
        return rBsearch(L, low, mid - 1, k);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I had a lot of things in mind while doing this! Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You did a mistake in calling the rBsearch method in the following lines
Instead of

```
else if (L[mid] < k) {
        return rBsearch(L, k, mid + 1, high); 
    } else {
        return rBsearch(L, k, low, mid - 1);
    }
```

You should use

```
else if (L[mid] < k) {
            return rBsearch(L,  mid + 1, high,k); //the order of the parameters
        } else {
            return rBsearch(L, low, mid - 1,k);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is:
Convert you array to list: `Arrays.asList(array)`

For sort: `Collections#sort`

For search: `Collections#binarySearch`

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Take Array From User
2. Sort Array using Build-in Function of Java...
3. then Search Element using Binary Search....

   ```
       import java.lang.reflect.Array;
       import java.util.Arrays;
       import java.util.Scanner;

       class BinarySearch
       {
          public static void main(String args[])
          {
             int array[];

             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("Enter number of elements:");
            int Size_Of_Array = input.nextInt(); 


             array = new int[Size_Of_Array];

             System.out.println("Enter " + Size_Of_Array + " integers");

             for (int counter = 0; counter < Size_Of_Array; counter++)
                 array[counter] = input.nextInt();

             Arrays.sort(array);
             System.out.println("Sorting Array is :-");
             for (int counter = 0; counter < Size_Of_Array; counter++)
                 System.out.println(array[counter]);

             System.out.println("Enter the search value:");
             int  Searching_item = input.nextInt();

             int First_Index=0;
             int Last_Index=Size_Of_Array-1;
             int Middle_Index=(First_Index+Last_Index)/2;

             while(First_Index <= Last_Index)
             {
                 if(array[Middle_Index] < Searching_item)
                 {
                     First_Index=Middle_Index+1;
                 }
                 else if ( array[Middle_Index] == Searching_item ) 
                 {
                   System.out.println(Searching_item + " found at location " + (Middle_Index + 1) + ".");
                   break;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Last_Index = Middle_Index - 1;
                 }
                 Middle_Index = (First_Index + Last_Index)/2;

                 if ( First_Index > Last_Index )
                 {
                     System.out.println(Searching_item + " is not found.\n");
                 }
             }
           }
       }
   ```

   [Result of BinarySearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8g4S.png)